# Black screen after kernel upgrade to 5.11.0-25-generic

Tags: upgrade, display, display-resolution

I'm using 3 monitors 1920x1080 (laptop and two external) on Ubuntu 21.04. After kernel upgrade from  5.11.0-18-generic to 5.11.0-25-generic the built-in monitor started to show only a black screen, the two other monitors work properly. If I try to start only with a laptop monitor it shows the black screen too. If I use a previous version of the kernel it works properly.

Comment: Compare `/lib/modules/5.11.0-18-generic` and `/lib/modules/5.11.0-25-generic` folders - maybe you lost some custom modules used in previous kernel.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue but with Worksation and 3 1080p monitors (2x DP 1x DVI)
With 5.8.0-63 it's working fine, with 5.11.0-25 only one screen starts black with the cursor.
I'm currently using 2x Quadro 2000/2000D with Nvidia driver and Mosaic in order to be
able to support 3 screens as the Quadro 2000 only supports 1 screen.

It doesn't seem to be anything kernel modules related. I had plenty of issues setting up the Mosaic and the 3 screens so should be something more Xorg/Nvidia related.

Comment: root@Z600W:/lib/modules# ls -lA 5.11.0-25-generic/ | awk -F':[0-9]* ' '/:/{print $2}'
build -> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-25-generic
initrd
kernel
misc
modules.alias
modules.alias.bin
modules.builtin
modules.builtin.alias.bin
modules.builtin.bin
modules.builtin.modinfo
modules.dep
modules.dep.bin
modules.devname
modules.order
modules.softdep
modules.symbols
modules.symbols.bin
vdso

Comment: root@Z600W:/lib/modules# ls -lA 5.8.0-63-generic/ | awk -F':[0-9]* ' '/:/{print $2}'
build -> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-63-generic
initrd
kernel
misc
modules.alias
modules.alias.bin
modules.builtin
modules.builtin.alias.bin
modules.builtin.bin
modules.builtin.modinfo
modules.dep
modules.dep.bin
modules.devname
modules.order
modules.softdep
modules.symbols
modules.symbols.bin
updates
vdso

Comment: This is what I've got during an apt upgrade booting with the 5.8.x kernel:

Building module:
cleaning build area...
[ ! -h /usr/bin/cc ] && export CC=/usr/bin/gcc; make -k module KERNDIR=/lib/modules/5.11.0-
27-generic IGNORE_XEN_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 SYSSRC=/lib/modules/5.11.0-27-generic
/build LD=/usr/bin/ld.bfd; make -C uvm module KERNEL_UNAME=5.11.0-27-generic KBUILD_EXTMOD=
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-340/340.108/build/uvm.............

It looks like the issue is nvidia driver related.

Comment: I can't reinstall drivers now due to the triple monitor settings and a specific Xorg config, but if you have nvidia gpu you can try, boot in rescue mode with the 5.11 kernel and attempt reinstalling nvidia proprietary drivers and try to boot again with the 5.11 kernel as usually.

Comment: I surrendered after reinstalling Ubuntu, rolled back to the 5.11.0-16 version, and all work properly.

Answer (score 0):

edit /etc/default/grub

change GRUB_DEFAULT=0 to GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2"

run cmd update-grub and reboot

Comment: edit /etc/default/grub

GRUB_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"

run cmd update-grub and reboot