# Black screen on boot after upgrade ubuntu server from 22.04 to 22.04.01

Tags: server, upgrade, 22.04

As title says i got a black screen after upgrade my ubuntu server from 22.04 to 22.04.1 upgrade went well without errors, services work as intended i can ssh to server and manage it from there but i got a black screen on my monitor.

Any suggestion on how should I proceed?

Comment: Check the related questions on the right about the same issue. Some of the posts have answers that may be useful to you. Here's just one of the 3 posts: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353563/black-screen-after-kernel-upgrade-to-5-11-0-25-generic?rq=1

Comment: @user25406 thanks for awnser, i have checked similar problems before posting but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that work for me was:

> Temporary Fix To get the system to boot:
>
> 1. After turning on your PC, hold the right SHIFT key to get to the GRUB
>    bootloader if your computer uses a BIOS. If your computer uses EFI or
>    UEFI, continuously tap the “ESC” (escape) key after turning on your
>    PC.
> 2. Once GRUB is open, press the “e” key to edit the first highlighted
>    entry “Ubuntu”. Move your cursor down to the line that starts with
>    “linux”, and use the right arrow key to find the section with the
>    words “ro quiet splash”.
> 3. Add “nomodeset” after these words.
> 4. Feel free to remove “quiet” and “splash” for more verbosity to
>    troubleshoot the boot process. Press “CTRL + X” or “F10” to boot.
>
> The system should now boot.
>
> Permanent Fix To permanently resolve the issue:
>
> 1. Once the system has booted using the temporary fix, log in.
> 2. Open a terminal window (Applications -> Terminal, or press the “Start” button and type terminal).
> 3. Either “su” in to root, or use “sudo” to open your favorite text editor and edit the file “/etc/default/grub” (I use nano which can be install by running “apt install nano”):
>
> nano /etc/default/grub
>
> 4. Locate the line with the variable “GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT”, and add “nomodeset” to the variables. Feel free to remove “splash” and “quiet” if you’d like text boot. Here’s an example of my line after editing (yours will look
>    different):
>
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
>
> 5. Save
>    the file and exit the text editor (CTRL+X to quit, the press “y” and
>    enter to save).
> 6. At the bash prompt, execute the following command to
>    regenerate the grub.conf file on the /boot partition from your new
>    default file:
>
> update-grub
>
> 7. Restart your system, it should now boot!

Solution foun on:

https://www.stephenwagner.com/2019/05/05/ubuntu-linux-black-screen-frozen-system-after-upgrade-install/

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had access non-GUI terminal and simply reinstalled `ubuntu-desktop`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

- https://devicetests.com/fix-ubuntu-black-screen-after-upgrade-2