# UBUNTU 22.04.2 LTS Does not work correctly with RTX4090

Tags: boot, kernel, dependencies, gui, acpi

PC specs:

- CPU: 12th Gen Intel Core i9-12900k
- GPU: NVIDIA RTX4090 Gigabyte
- Motherboard: Z690 Ace
- GNOME 42.5

I have Ubuntu installed on the above PC, but since then there are many problems with:

1. kernel error: whit kern.log ERROR :

   ubuntu kernel:

   ```
    [   0.448427] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS14.SADX], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
   ```
2. gpu-manager is not working: log [here](https://anonfiles.com/K9D488a5zd/gpu_manager_log)

   ```
    RTX4090 not working even with NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-525 (proprietary,tested) in software and updates app  and also I can't move anything to  my desktop using the mouse cursor and although files are visible in  the `~/Desktop` folder, I cannot see anything in the Desktop GUI. I've installed GNOME, but it didn't work.
   ```
3. Problem in bootlog:

   ```
   [DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD NSS Service responder socket.  
   [DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD…toFS Service responder socket.  
   [DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD PAC Service responder socket.  
   [DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD…vice responder private socket.  
   [DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD PAM Service responder socket.  
   [DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD SSH Service responder socket.  
   [DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD Sudo Service responder socket.
   ```

Comment: I see no problems here. Please remove unrelated stuff and make clear what you mean by "RTX4090 not working".

Comment: The "proprietary, tested" 525 driver is the "-open" one, try the 525 without the open (not the "server" one).

Comment: Thankyou for your response @Pilot6
about boot :
RTX itself is Ok but drivers are not : I have to boot in recovery mode always ,otherwise the screen go black and I can not do anything
about GUI :
I can not see anything in Desktop GUI

Comment: Did you disable Secure Boot?

Comment: Thankyou for your response @ubfan1 I have tryed all of them(not for server) , still the problems did not solve...

Comment: @Pilot6 no I did not

Comment: So disable Secure Boot and try. Also check if you added any options to grub. Maybe you disable the driver.

Comment: Disabled Secure Boot , Its the same.
 awk -F\' '/menuentry / {print $2}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg 
Ubuntu
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-32-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-32-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-43-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-43-generic (recovery mode)
UEFI Firmware Settings
Is this what you have mentioned to check? @Pilot6

Comment: Secure Boot is disabled in BIOS.

Comment: yes I have disabled Secure Boot in UEFI and here is grub options : GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" @Pilot6

Comment: Maybe a clean start -- sudo apt purge every package with "nvidia" in the name, then do the 525 install again.

Answer (score 1):

You disabled the driver yourself by adding `nomodeset` to grub options.

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and remove it.

Then run `sudo update-grub`.

The problem should be solved.

Comment: I aded nomodeset to grub after searching for a solution recommended [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1454370/black-screen-on-boot-after-upgrade-ubuntu-server-from-22-04-to-22-04-01/1455154#1455154) and now again I have removed nomodeset but its still the same @Pilot6