Ubuntu blank screen after an update (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)
For work I have to use Ubuntu, which is fine but if something goes wrong, I have no idea how to solve it. 2 weeks ago I updated Ubuntu, restarted my laptop and got blank screen. Laptop was on, but the system did not boot. Restared couple times, but nothing.
I did some digging and in almost every answer, the solution was to put nomodeset in the GRUB file, which should have solved the issue (according to https://askubuntu.com/a/1455154/1848692 for example).
It solved the issue but introduced a new issue. Now my second monitor is not getting signal from my laptop. So I figured, I cannot use nomodeset if I want to use my second monitor.
After that I tried to update the amd drivers with sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade and rebooted, but still nothing. Without nomodeset in GRUB I am getting blank screen.
Since then I had like 7 mini software updates, expecting the issue will resolve itself, but it did not. So if anyone can help, I will highly appreciate that.
I used the command lspci  -v -s  $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1) to see the software/hardware details if needed:
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: 
Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso/Raven 2 
[Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] 
(rev c2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad E595

Edit: Had another software update, got this now
Edit2: maybe useful info on boot and on boot 2

general approach for black screen is to boot up into Recovery Mode then from its menu choose root which will give you a terminal prompt logged in as root  ... from there  you can issue commands to fix it ... all particulars are google able

thanks, ill try that, but I do not know what is broken, so idk what and how to fix

With nomodeset you are not using the installed video drive but a generic one so no second monitor is to be expected. You only use nomodeset till you have fixed the issue and then remove it from the Grub.
